Visual Studio cmake project — add any files to the Solution Explorer (Target View)
I am trying to set up a Visual Studio 2022 CMake project for quick access to all the files I need (sources, headers, JSONs, or other text files).
I find the Target View in the Solution Explorer more convenient than the Folder View, but it only shows files added to the target using add_executable().
What are consequences of adding not just the source *.cpp files but also headers and any text files to add_executable(), such as the performance of the application, build time, or something else?
